# Multistep form click next, scroll to top rather than stay at bottom

Tags: jquery, forms

I have a form that proceeds to next step, however when it proceeds it stays at the bottom rather than going to top.

How can I do this?  I am using Jankos Form to Wizard plugin which is updated (http://www.style-card.co.uk/id/assets/js/formToWizard.js)

JSFiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/4Hkxy/9/

```
       $(function(){
            var $signupForm = $( '#multipage' );
 $signupForm.formToWizard({
                submitButton: 'SaveAccount',
                showProgress: true, //default value for showProgress is also true
                nextBtnName: 'Forward >>',
                prevBtnName: '<< Previous',
                showStepNo: false,
                validateBeforeNext: function() {
                    var selectedCount = $('.thumbnails.image_picker_selector:visible .selected').length;
    var totalCount = $('.thumbnails.image_picker_selector:visible').length;

    if(selectedCount != totalCount) {
        alert('please select an image per selection');
    return false;
}
return true;
                }
            });
       });

$("select.image-picker").imagepicker({
    hide_select: true,
    show_label: true,
});
$("select.image-picker.show-labels").imagepicker({
    hide_select: true,
    show_label: true,
});

var container = $("select.image-picker.masonry").next("ul.thumbnails");
container.imagesLoaded(function () {
    container.masonry({
        itemSelector: "li",
    });
});
```

Comment: [Use jQuery ScrollTo](http://flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/)

Comment: Thanks - I ended up using $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow');